# Из массива надо вывести конкретные данные по ключам PHP

Tags: php

ПОМОГИТЕ 3 ДНЯ МУЧАЮСЬ!! Из бд вывожу массив а дальше не пойму что к чему голову сломал уже.

Массив в таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [object_id] => 2030
    [object_type] => O
    [status] => 
    [field_id] => 81
    [value] => წერეთლის 2
)
Array
(
    [object_id] => 2030
    [object_type] => O
    [status] => 
    [field_id] => 85
    [value] => სერგო ზაქარიაძის 12
)
Array
(
    [object_id] => 2030
    [object_type] => O
    [status] => 
    [field_id] => 88
    [value] => 557 57 95 79
)
Array
(
    [object_id] => 2030
    [object_type] => O
    [status] => 
    [field_id] => 97
    [value] => 557 57 95 79
)
Array
(
    [object_id] => 2030
    [object_type] => O
    [status] => 
    [field_id] => 99
    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [object_id] => 2030
    [object_type] => O
    [status] => 
    [field_id] => 113
    [value] => 
)
```

Надо вывести в переменную определенные поля такие как value по определенным ключам field_id. То есть у field_id => 85 value это адрес, а у field_id => 88 value это контактный номер этого адреса.

```
Надо вывести следующим образом:
Номер заказчика[value] -> (field_id[88]);
1) адрес[value] -> (field_id[81]) - номер[value] -> (field_id[97]);
2) адрес[value] -> (field_id[85]) - номер[value] -> (field_id[99]);
Это все у одного object_id. Такой массив вывожу в цикле с разными object_id
```

структура бд такая:

```
object_id     object_type      status      field_id       value
2030              O             N              81        წერეთლის 2
2030              O             N              85        სერგო ზაქარიაძის 12
2030              O             N              88        557 57 95 79
и т.д..
```

Перед всем этим у меня цикл такой:

```
    $shipping_name = "SELECT * FROM cscart_orders WHERE shipping_ids = $shipping_descriptions_2 ORDER BY cscart_orders.order_id DESC";

    $shipping_name_0 = mysqli_query($link, $shipping_name);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shipping_name_0)) {
    $id_order = $row[order_id];

$number_9 = "SELECT * FROM cscart_profile_fields_data WHERE object_id = $id_order";
$number_data_9_0 = mysqli_query($link, $number_9);
```

ну а потом сортирую через foreach:

```
foreach($number_data_9_0 as $key => $massiv){ }
}
```

пробовал и через `while ($rowis_0_00 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($number_data_9_0 )) {}`
получаю одно и тоже.

Comment: У вас нету признака, по которому нужно сопоставлять данные значения.

Comment: От нас вы что хотите увидеть-то?

Comment: @Mamuka привет. добавьте к вопросу запрос, которым вы достаёте данные и может даже структуру таблиц из который вы их получаете. Очень похоже что решать надо на уровне таблиц.

Comment: Сейчас у меня организованно все таким образом: $number_8 = "SELECT * FROM cscart_profile_fields_data WHERE object_id = $id_order AND field_id = '123'";   $number_data_8_0 = mysqli_query($link, $number_8);    $rowis_0_8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($number_data_8_0);   и получаю каждый value так $rowis_0_8[value]   но код так очень большой получается да и запрос к бд не один раз проходит а хочется как то все это сократить и красиво чтоб было. Надеюсь вы меня поняли спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: @Евгений Николаев - согласен с вами как его присвоить подскажите а то уже 3 дня мучаюсь ничего не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValueByFieldId(array $arData, int $fieldId): array {
    $result = [];
    foreach($arData as $value)
        if($value["field_id"] == $fieldId)
            $result[] = [$fieldId => $value];
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю выше указанная функция не работает в цикле. как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так:

```
   $arr = array();

       while ($rowzz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($number_data_9_0)) {
            $arr[$rowzz['object_id']][$rowzz['field_id']] = $rowzz['value'];
        }
        $ids_81 = array_column($arr, '81');
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то у Вас две таблицы связаны order_id = object_id. Получается можно все ваши запросы объединить в один.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
  FROM cscart_orders AS co 
  LEFT JOIN cscart_profile_fields AS cpf ON co.order_id = cpf.object_id
  WHERE co.shipping_ids = $shipping_descriptions_2";

$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
```